# Is there a working on-the-fly compilation in NetBeans 6.5 and how well is it doing?

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation

I learned today that NetBeans 6.5 should have an on-the-fly compilation of (single) Java files. This feature is well known from Eclipse: Simply store the file and the compiled class is stored, too. Is NetBeans working the same way? If not, how is it ticking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the same I believe...

[Here's a video showing it in action](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/compile-on-save-screencast.html)